# How to access the tweet history conversation using TweetSharp?

Tags: twitter, tweetsharp

I am trying to access a tweet conversation history using TweetSharp.

The  requirement is like, if I use id of one tweet item it should
return me the whole thread that followed before that tweet item.

But could not find such method exposed through TwittertService, where
I can pass the current Tweet _id and get the conversation details.

I followed the following approach to get the collection (list) ie,

```cs
List<TwitterStatus> list = new List<TwitterStatus>();


private void GetReplied(TwitterStatus twitter, TwitterResponse twitterResponse)
{
    if (twitter.InReplyToStatusId != null)
    {
        long statusID = (long)twitter.InReplyToStatusId;
        this.ts.GetTweet(statusID, (twitterRecursive,
                                    twitterResponseRecursive) =>
                                    {
                                        list.Add(twitterRecursive);
                                        if (twitter.InReplyToStatusId != null)
                                        {
                                            this.GetReplied(twitterRecursive,
                                                            twitterResponseRecursive);
                                        }
                                    });
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(list.Count);
        foreach (TwitterStatus status in list)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(status.Text);
        }
    }
}

this.ts.GetTweet(<tweet Id>, twitterResponse) =>
{
        list.Add(twitter);
        this.GetReplied(twitter, twitterResponse);
});
```

Just wanted to have your advice, on that. Do we have any such method
with TweetSharp or any alternative approach can be implemented?

Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that's how you'll have to do it: start with a tweet and walk its `in_reply_to_status_id` chain.

One thing I do, although it may not be applicable to you, is check a local cache of tweets before fetching from Twitter to see if I already fetched the tweet being replied to.

As for libraries that make this easier, I don't know of any.  Regardless of whether they expose a more streamlined method, under the covers they'll still have to perform the process that you implemented in your code.

To see how another library approached this task, take a look at [this Twitterizer sample](http://www.twitterizer.net/530/reconstructing-a-conversation/).